# 2.426.1 runs perfectly fine but rolling up to 2.426.2 provides unclear Java issues

Tags: docker, jenkins

Considering the minimal changelist, we updated from 2.426.1 > .2 this morning and have since rolled back.

Nothing super descriptive but we were getting this error when we weren't before:
`Caused: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.servlet.LocalStrings, locale en_US`

We run our jenkins controller in a docker container if this happens to be a docker specific issue.

Simply an update to the latest version of Jenkins through Docker.